# How does Nano run on terminal?

Tags: shell

So, I am using a shell and I am able to use the Nano text editor on it. How is Nano able to run and visually appear on a shell if shell is a command line interpreter? I thought only terminals can handle text editors because they are text input/output environment.

Comment: You may learn more about how shell editors like nano here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179299/how-do-shell-text-editors-work

Comment: You can think about it like this: Your terminals are "virtual hardware" that accept input and output. Your shells are programs that run in the terminals. When you launch nano in your shell, your shell not only starts nano but also "tells" nano that nano can now use the input/output from the terminal and your shell will decouple itself from the the terminal's input/output. It will still continue running in the background to "control" nano when necessary.

Comment: @zevzek Correct, this is why i mentioned "think about it like this" instead of "it works like this".

Comment: Your shell is running inside a terminal, isn't it?

Comment: the shell is just an interpreter for the BASH scripting language, the terminal is a wrapper program for the shell. In other words, the terminal is not the shell, it's basically just the graphical interface. Terminals used to be the machine through which you issue commands to some large computerized unit, they serve a similar purpose now but it's just a little window that allows you to control your computer.